# Identifying VSS drives in SCOM 2012 R2

Tags: vss, scom

I'm trying to configure some overrides in our SCOM 2012 R2 server to disable disk space alerts on our VSS drives. I could just go in and disable it on every VSS drive we have, but it'd be good if I can make it more dynamic. I just can't seem to figure out how to identify a volume shadow copy drive in SCOM. Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm trying to think how I'd go about identifying a copy target, and I'm not sure there's an easy way to do it.